# add_filter img_caption_shortcode not implemented

Tags: plugin-development, shortcode, captions

In a plugin I am creating, I need to change the output of the `[caption]`. I do this with (as from the Codex and other examples here)

```
add_filter('img_caption_shortcode', 'caption_fix', 10, 3);

function caption_fix ($x, $att, $content) {
   $content = 'new caption' ; // change it
return $content; }
```

But the `[caption] ... [/caption]` is still in the output; instead of "new caption" is expected to be in the output.

I have verified that the caption code is enabled with this code:

```
if (  shortcode_exists("caption")) { die("found caption shortcode"); }
```

And the generated page dies as expected.

Have carefully checked my caption_fix function to ensure that is returning content (if empty return $content, normal caption shortcode function is done).

This is with WP 4.8.1 and PHP > 5.3. (Added: WP 4.8.2 does same thing.)

Ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(gotta read the docs a bit more carefully)

I was using this code in the loop

```
$xcontent =get_the_content();
```

But `get_the_content()` does not apply filters ... as the documentation states (if I was paying attention). I should use `the_content()`, or change it to this (which is the same as `the_content()`) :

```
$xcontent =get_the_content();
$xcontent = apply_filters('the_content', $xcontent);
```

So the issue was that filters were not being applied, since I used `get_the_content()` instead of `the_content()` .

That problem solved. Now on to the next one, with more careful reading of the Codex docs...